# How to use the output of function 1 in function2 in R?

Tags: r

I need to call the output from function1 in function2 for estimating purposes.

```
x=function(param)
{
 z=param^2
}

y=function(param1)
{
 q=z
 zz=q*3
}
```

How to define z in fonction x to be able to call z later in function y?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call function x in y :

```
x <- function(param1){param1^2}  
y <- function(param2){x(param2)*3}
```